# Count rows in multiple csv's, write to csv's as new column in descending order

Tags: r, macos, csv

I need help editing multiple csv's within a folder.  I need to count the number of rows in each file, and add a new column to the files.  The new column should have the number of rows as the first row in the column, and then descend by 1 for each subsequent row.

```
Current:
ID  V1  V2  V3
1   0.4625  0.917
2   0.9324  0.248
3   0.6691  0.781
4   0.1935  0.330

Proposed:
ID  V1   V2  V3   newcol  
1   0.4  25  0.9  5
2   0.9  24  0.2  4
3   0.6  91  0.7  3
4   0.1   5  0.3  2
5   0.2  44  0.5  1
```

Anyone have any ideas? I've been playing around with the terminal and trying to do it that way.  I also have some minor experience with r.  I'm also using a mac if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
df1$newcol <- rev(seq_len(nrow(df1)))
```

Or

```
df1$newcol <-  nrow(df1):1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, akrun.  Unfortunately I think your answer went right over my head.  Does your answer imply that I first need to load the csv's as data frames in r, and then modify that way?  Also, I'm imagining I need a loop here.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @cdwhiteiv  If you have csv file, then you may need to read it with `read.csv/read.table` create an object `df` i.e. `df <- read.csv('yourfile.csv')` and then create the column

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried to below, but it seems that it didn't work.  Something I didn't mention is that I'll then need to export these data frames back into csv format.

Comment: @cdwhiteiv You can export it using `write.csv(df1, "yourfile.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: `for(i in filenames) {
    filepath <- file.path(".../pathname", paste(i))
    assign(i,filepath)
    df <- read.csv(filepath)
    df$newcol <- rev(seq_len(nrow(df)))
}`

Comment: @cdwhiteiv  I would do `filenames <- list.files(pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE); lst <- lapply(filenames, function(x) {x1 <- read.csv(x); transform(x1, newcol = rev(seq_len(nrow(df))))}); lapply(seq_along(filenames), function(i) write.csv(lst[[i]], basename(filenames[i]), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE))`

Answer (score 1):

Got it!  With akrun's guidance I was able to successfully add a column to each csv, with the rows in the new column in descending order.  I was then able to write it back to the original files!

```
filenames <- list.files(path=".../pathoffolder", pattern=".*csv")

for(i in filenames) {
   filepath <- file.path(".../pathoffolder", paste(i))
   assign(i,filepath)
   df <- read.csv(filepath)
   df$newcol <- rev(seq_len(nrow(df)))
   write.csv(df, filepath, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```